# Route isn't passing variables to controller when used in blade

Tags: laravel

I'm using a named route in a view, passing two variables with it, but it throws the error that no arguments are passed.

I know that I could just construct the url for the href, but from what I've read so far is that what I'm trying should work just fine too (and I'm not seeing what I'm doing different from the documentation examples really).

link in show.blade.php

`<a href="{{ route('tasks.create', ['colony_slug' => $colony->slug, 'action_name' => 'change_name']) }}">Change Name</a>`

in the browser the link shows up as

```
http://localhost/tasks/create?colony_slug=labr-oclh&action_name=change_name
```

route in web.php

```
Route::get('tasks/create/{colony_slug}/{action_name}', 'TaskController@create')->name('tasks.create');
```

TaskController@create

```
// CREATE ACTION
// =========================================================================
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @param string $colony_slug
     * @param string $action_name
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create($colony_slug, $action_name)
    {
        dd($colony_slug . " " . $action_name);
    }
```

the error

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected
```

the routes list

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks                                    | tasks.index                      | App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@index                              | web,auth
         |
|        | POST      | tasks                                    | tasks.store                      | App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@store                              | web,auth
         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks/create/{colony_slug}/{action_name} | tasks.create                     | App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@create                             | web,auth
         |
|        | PUT|PATCH | tasks/{task}                             | tasks.update                     | App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@update                             | web,auth
         |
|        | DELETE    | tasks/{task}                             | tasks.destroy                    | App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@destroy                            | web,auth
         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks/{task}                             | tasks.show                       | App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@show                               | web,auth
         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | tasks/{task}/edit                        | tasks.edit                       | App\Http\Controllers\TaskController@edit                               | web,auth
         |
|
```

Comment: If you replace `($colony_slug, $action_name)` with `(Request $request)`, then dd($request), what's the output?

Comment: Do you have another route with only the path `tasks/create` - no parameters? The URL being generated by `route()` is creating a query string instead of URI parameters, which makes me think there's a conflict and it's grabbing the wrong one.

Comment: @UkraineInTheMembrane which parts of dd($request) do you need?

Comment: @AkenRoberts 
ah this seems indeed to causing trouble. There was a Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController') right under it. I've added an exception and indeed that was indeed grabbing it. As it now appears that the intended one was ignoring the uri because it didn't have the /{colony_slug}/{action_name}
how do I make the route accept both:

http://localhost/tasks/create?colony_slug=labr-oclh&action_name=change_name

and

http://localhost/tasks/create/labr-oclh/change_name

Comment: I guess there is another route overwriting it. Could you show us your route file content?

Comment: @LuisBrito

I've added the route list. I've tried a few more things. The problem seems that the two arguments added to the route when I call it in the blade and are added as variables behind the '?' in the generated URL, are somehow not put into the required arguments between '{}' in the route definition.

I don't understand why as this seems exactly like the example given here:https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes

Comment: try this `Route::get('tasks/create/colony/{colony_slug}/action/{action_name}', 'TaskController@create')->name('tasks.create');`

Comment: Reproducing your context I noticed that the link should be http://localhost/tasks/create/labr-oclh/change_name and not http://localhost/tasks/create?colony_slug=labr-oclh&action_name=change_name. Query parameters are not passed to route. I didn't figure out yet why route() generated your link with query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discovered through comment questions, the issue is your custom route conflicting with a Resource Controller route. Specifically in the route name (via `named()`), which should always be unique even if they use the same URI.

There are a couple solutions you can use, depending on what your functionality goal is:

**Solution for: I only want one "Create Task" route**

Disable the `task.create` route created by the resource controller by using the `except()` modifier:

```php
Route::resource('tasks', 'TasksController')->except(['create']);
```

Leave your other route definition as-is. This will remove the URI `/tasks/create` from your app, and leave the one with the additional parameters.

**Solution for: I want to use both**

The route paths themselves are okay, and are only conflicting via the name. Name your custom route something different, and use it when you want to use the extra parameters.

```php
Route::get('tasks/create/{colony_slug}/{action_name}', 'TaskController@create')->name('tasks.create-custom');
```

**Solution for: I want to specify defaults on my Create Task form**

I'm guessing that you're using these parameters in order to set some default values in your Create Task form. If that's what your end goal is, using the default Resource Controller route + query string parameters would work equally well, and won't involve extra routes.

1. Remove your extra custom route, and stick with the defaults from the Resource Controller
2. Declare a `Illuminate\Http\Request` dependency in your `create()` controller method:

   ```
   public function create(Request $request)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Check for [query string values in the request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input), and add them as defaults to your form.

Comment: This was indeed the biggest culprit. When I fixed this it wasn't working yet, but then at least my errors were landing closer to the problem. I'm not exactly sure what I changed after that, but after some more tweaking it suddenly worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I look to all the code you provide it looks correct to me.
Maybe you should check your routes file. Remember routes have presedence top to botton, if you had another route with similar name **it could be that this one is having precedence over the one you are tryint to use.**